# IndexError: list index out of range where?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code should solve the sudoku normally, is my text file wrong?

I'm getting this error:

> D:\Oneg\Python\sudoku2.py", line 85, in estDansSousMatrice
>       if grille[i][j]==v: IndexError: list index out of range

```
309000400
200709000
087000000
750060230
600904008
028050041
000000590
000106007
006000104
```

This is my code:

```
def estDansSousMatrice(grille, l, c, v):
    bc = (c / 3) * 3
    bl = (l / 3) * 3

    for i in range(int(bl), int(bl) + 3):
        for j in range(int(bc), int(bc) + 3):
            if grille[i][j] == v:
               return True
    return False
```

My text open like that:

```
def charge(nom_du_fichier):
    mon_fichier = open(nom_du_fichier, "r")
    x = [[0] * 9 for i in range(9)]
    for j in range(9):
        line = mon_fichier.readline().split(" ")
    for i in range(len(line)):
        if line[i].isdigit():
            x[j][i] = int(line[i])
        else:      
            return(x)
```

Comment: Maybe debug the indexes in that loop and find when and then why they are _out of range_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3, the expression `(c / 3) * 3` is always going to be a float with the same value as `c`. If you want to be rounding down to the nearest multiple of three, you either need to explicitly call `int` on the part in parentheses, or use the `//` operator to request "floor" division rather than "true" division (which you get from the `/` operator).

I suspect this is the cause of your index issues. When the coordinates you call the function with are in the last three rows or columns, you'll eventually get an index that's out of bounds.

Try using:

```
bc = c // 3 * 3  # the parentheses were not necessary
bl = l // 3 * 3
```